# R: Stagewise regression, multiplying with a basis vector

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression

I have this algorithm from [this](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/stagewise.pdf) paper: 
[image]

I tried to implement it in R, but the dimensions are not correct when I multiply with, [image] the *i-th* standard basis vector in [image]

Here is my code so far:

```
#initializing matrices
Boston <- read.csv("train.csv")
Boston=na.omit(Boston)
x=model.matrix(crim~.,Boston)[,-c(1,2)]
rownames(x)=c()
y=as.matrix(Boston$crim)
value1=matrix(0,13,1)
value=matrix(0,13,1)

#defining a 0 beta vector 13x1 and epsilon
beta=as.matrix(rep(0,13))
epsilon=0.1

#defining a matrix for the standard basis vecor
e=matrix(0,13,13)
for(t in 1:13){
  e[t,t]=as.matrix(1)
}

for(k in 1:13){
 #Finding the maximum i
  for(j in 1:13){
    value[j]=t(x)[j,]%*%(y-x%*%beta)
    value=abs(value)
    i=which.max(value)
  }
  #defining the standard basis vector
  e_basis=matrix(e[,i],13,1)

  value1[k]=epsilon*sign(t(x)[i,]%*%(y-x%*%beta))
  beta=beta+value1
}
```

The code compiles, but I'm not sure if I implemented everything else except the basis vector correctly.

The `train.csv` file (Boston dataset) can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/boston-housing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get comes from the fact that when you compute `sign(t(x)[i,]%*%(y-x%*%beta))`, you don't get a numeric value, you actually get a matrix of size 1. You can extract the sign value from the matrix by adding `[1,1]` for example. By doing so, you will be able to compute `epsilon*sign(t(x)[i,]%*%(y-x%*%beta))[1,1]*e_basis`.

Now another thing that surprised me is that, in your code, `k` loops from 1 to 13 which is the number of predictors, yet `k` is completely unrelated to this number since `k` represents the iteration step of your algorithm.

Having said that, `value1` (not `value1[k]`) should be storing the vector `epsilon*sign(t(x)[i,]%*%(y-x%*%beta))[1,1]*e_basis`.

Now to get your code working as described in the paper, if I didn't understand wrong, I would rewrite your solution like this:

```
Boston <- read.csv("../train.csv")
#initializing matrices
Boston=na.omit(Boston)
x=model.matrix(crim~.,Boston)[,-c(1:2)]
rownames(x)=c()
y=as.matrix(Boston$crim)
value1=matrix(0,13,1)
value=matrix(0,13,1)

#defining a 0 beta vector 13x1 and epsilon
beta=as.matrix(rep(0,13))
epsilon=0.1

#defining a matrix for the standard basis vecor
e=matrix(0,13,13)
for(t in 1:13){
  e[t,t]=as.matrix(1) 
}

n_iterations <- 10

for(k in 1:n_iterations){
  #Finding the maximum i
  for(j in 1:13){
    value[j]=t(x)[j,]%*%(y-x%*%beta)
    value=abs(value)
  }

  i=which.max(value)

  #defining the standard basis vector
  e_basis=matrix(e[,i],13,1)

  value1=epsilon*sign(t(x)[i,]%*%(y-x%*%beta))[1,1]*e_basis
  beta=beta+value1
}
```

Comment: thank you, but with your solution I get the betas in the end all zero

Comment: You need to choose an appropriate value for your step. It appears that having `epsilon = 0.1` is too high here. You can try much smaller values of `epsilon` (e.g `epsilon = 0.00001`). You can also set a high number of iterations (e.g `n_iterations = 25000`) and see how it works. Then you can compare your betas to the ones obtained with a lasso selection procedure `glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, lambda = 0.25)$beta`.

Comment: thank you, I tried a smaller value of epsilon and a larger number of iterations, and now I get some beta coefficients.